# Is there a way to use variables in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

I am trying to use `SOAPUI` to send a request to a REST API. Is there a way to use variables?

E.g if the post request looks like this

```
{
   "eventType": "check",
   "emailAddress": "email@emailtesting.com",
   "source": "mobile",
   "customerSegment": "gold",
   "custId": "1111111111"
}
```

Can I use variables instead of let's say the value *gold*?

Comment: Answered a similar question on Stackoverflow.  You may find it useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647467/how-to-use-the-properrty/11661412#11661412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SoapUI supports something called "properties" which are essentially the variables you asked for.  After setting a property, whether manually or by a Groovy script, [properties](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html) can be included in your individual test steps.  SoapUI will expand a properties reference to whatever the property's value is.  Property references look like this:  ${property_name}.

```
Property: CustSegment = Gold
{ "eventType": "check", 
"emailAddress": "email@emailtesting.com", 
"source": "mobile", 
"customerSegment": "${CustSegment}", 
"custId": "1111111111" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer from the SoapUI forum:

> depends where "do the variables belong"  - you choose a scope eg. custId (i believe it is sth like customerID) in TestCase scope, if you need the custId visible in all teststeps
>
> Lets have the example on TestCase scope - you go to Custom Properties tab in soapui (left bottom corner), create there a property (variable) you need = "custId" with value "1111". Then this variable is accessible in all testSteps:
>
> ```
> {
> "eventType": "check",
> "emailAddress": "email@emailtesting.com",
> "source": "mobile",
> "customerSegment": "gold",
> "custId": "${#TestCase#custId}" [-> will expand to 1111]
> }
> ```

Comment: The scopes are described on https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html

Comment: And what #TestCase means?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can use script properties and a data source.

Data source is my preference as you can build data driven tests, but not in the free version.

You can also create a Groovey step that can either return a const or calculated value and then access that value in your request as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get it from a data source like excel file. For example if you want to get CustId column of your excel you can use following :

```
{

   "eventType": "check",

   "emailAddress": "email@emailtesting.com",

   "source": "mobile",

   "customerSegment": "gold",

   "custId": $(DataSource#CustId)

}
```